# Vue.js push/upshift not adding new item into array.It does't even show any error

Tags: vue.js

```
<template>
  <div class="tc-notes-wrapper">
    <AddNewButton @click="addNote"/>
    <div class="tc-notes">
      <div v-for="(note, index) in notes" :key="index" @deleteNote="deleteNote" >
        <div class="tc-note">
          <div class="tc-note-header">
            <span @click="deleteNote(index)" class="tc-note-close"> X </span>

            <div class="tc-note-title" contenteditable="">
              {{ note.title }}
            </div>
            <div class="tc-note-body" contenteditable="">
              {{ note.body }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AddNewButton from "../components/AddNewButton";
export default {
  name: "Notes",
  components: {
    AddNewButton,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      notes: [
        {
          title: "sunt aut facere repellat",
          body:
            "uia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto",
        },       
        {
          title: "nesciunt quas odio",
          body:
            "repudiandae veniam quaerat sunt sed alias aut fugiat sit autem sed est",
        },
              
      ],
      note: [{title:'',body:''}]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    deleteNote(index) {
      this.notes.splice(index, 1);
    },
    addNote() {
      this.notes.unshift({ title: 'test', body: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) })
    }
  
  },
};
</script>
```

I posted a complete code just to make it clear. I am making a note-taking app. I tried all the solutions nothing is working. It shows no errors. This is the complete code now (that add button has no special code in it just a button component).

Comment: I tried the Delete function, it is working fine only adding a new one is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I agree with @Paul-Louis Mas and There is a spelling mistake in notes `tittle` . I did update your code, check this out

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div>
            <div v-for="note in notes">{{ note.title }} - {{ note.body }}</div>
        </div>
        <button @click="addNote">Add Note</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      notes: [
        {
          title: "hunt",
          body: "babe bear"
        },
        {
          title: "arrow",
          body: "bow"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addNote() {
      this.notes.unshift({ title: 'test', body: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
    #app {
        font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        text-align: center;
        color: #2c3e50;
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, Naren :) Really helped in resolving as I got confident because of your answer that the function is correct, the error was in the button rather than in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing `this.notes` as if it was an object, because you are accessing the properties `title` and `body`, but in your data, `notes` is an array.

Also, the way you defined your `data` is incorrect, the `notes` array is not formatted correcly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I did not do that initially, I was using "this.notes.unshift({title:' ',body: ' '}). it did not work so Someone suggested to me that referencing method.